# How to get the matched expression in GNU Recutils?

Tags: regular-expression, gnu

In the GNU Recutils [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/manual/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions), it is written that

> The longest possible match is returned; this applies to the regular expression as a whole and (subject to this constraint) to sub-expressions within groups.

However, when I run the following command (on macOS, with recutils installed via homebrew)

```
echo "Author: Knuth, Donald E." | recfmt "{{Author ~ '^([^,]+).*'}}"
```

I get the boolean `1` as a result.

I think the regex is correct since the following command correctly returns `Knuth`.

```
echo "Knuth, Donald E." | sed  -E "s/^([^,]+).*/\1/"
```

Did I misunderstand the manual or is this a bug? If so, is there another way to get the match rather than a boolean?

**Update.** I got the same behaviour with a Debian virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` operator is a comparison operator: it answers the question, "does the string on the left match the expression on the right?", and it returns a boolean value as a result.

So when you run:

```
echo "Author: Knuth, Donald E." | recfmt "{{Author ~ '^([^,]+).*'}}"
```

The expression `Author ~ '^([^,]+).*'` evaluates to `1` because the value of the `Author` field matches the given expression.

I don't believe the template language provides any sort of transformation capability (you can't filter/cut/modify fields as part of a template). You can, of course, post-process the output of something like `recsel` using `sed`, `awk` or other tools.